# Reduce mapStateToProps execution time

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a normalized state in [redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux) reducers and want to have joined objects as view model, like post, comments and likes. So on each action `mapStateToProps` performs heavy lifting with custom joins between three collections. Is there a way to avoid this expensive recalculation?

I've heard of `reselect` but can't get the idea of how do I use it in my case.

Reducers state looks like this:

```
posts: {'postId':{...postDataWithReferenesToCommentsAndLikeAuthors}}
comments: {'commentId':{...commentDataWithReferenesToCommentAuthors}}
users: {'userId':{...userData}}
```

I'm merging this maps in `mapStateToProps` on each single post or comment edit, and it's slow to unusable.

[The whole situation sketch](https://gist.github.com/kadmil/ad715b26f14df17c781f)

Comment: Do you need an example/explanation of how to use reselect for your usecase?

Comment: @lukewestby yep, or maybe general advice.

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev from what I understand from [react-redux docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) `mapStateToProps` is your custom code, so you just want to optimize this function, and the problem as such has nothing to with neither react nor redux. Immutable data libraries might help you. If you need more details, please tell us more about your `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: Please provide a full runnable example, then we can look at optimizing it. In general I don't think restoring the tree before rendering is the right way.

Comment: @DanAbramov https://gist.github.com/kadmil/ad715b26f14df17c781f